# SSH keys fail for Fedora 25

Tags: ssh, fedora, selinux

I am trying to set up key-based ssh access to a Fedora 25 box. I have done this on many Ubuntu servers with no issues. I get `Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).`

Here is my set up process:

1. (server) create /home/[user]/.ssh
2. (local) copy key.pub to remote /home/[user]/.ssh/authorized_keys
3. (server) chmod 700 /home/[user]/.ssh
4. (server) chmod 600 /home/[user]/.ssh/authorized_keys
5. (server) chown -R [user]:[user] /home/[user]/.ssh/

I ran sshd in verbose mode. But, I cannot interpret the output. I think this is the pertinent bit:

`debug1: SELinux support enabled [preauth]
debug1: ssh_selinux_change_context: setting context from 'unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023' to 'unconfined_u:unconfined_r:sshd_net_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023' [preauth]
debug3: ssh_selinux_change_context: setcon unconfined_u:unconfined_r:sshd_net_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 from unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 failed with Invalid argument [preauth]`

Is something in SELinux my problem? Other places I should look?

**EDIT**

Here is a link to gist with the results of ssh -vvv:
https://gist.github.com/RogerCreasy/527d7520ce356074f4737ced51fb886d

And, a link to a gist with sshd_config:
https://gist.github.com/RogerCreasy/1105333c869a08193754410679e81335

Comment: `restorecon ~/.ssh` or something like that? If not, is there anything else relevant logged on the sshd side?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist tired restorecon...what else could I look for in the logs?

Comment: The private key authentication is not used for some reason. It looks like the server does not offer this auth method. What is the server `sshd_config`? How do you start the `sshd` service to get this error? What AVCs are in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`?

Comment: @Jakuje - I added a link to a copy of `sshd_config` .  There are no AVCs in `audit.log` (Thank you!)

Comment: https://blog.tinned-software.net/ssh-key-authentication-is-not-working-selinux/ maybe ?

Comment: @daftaupe not that case. The public key authentication is not even used in the attached log. What is in the client configuration. Can't be the public key authentication disabled there?

Comment: @Jakuje - That was it! well, something in the local config. However, pub key auth was not overridden.... Not sure what was wrong, but without the local config it works. If you will post something as an answer, I will accept and upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public key authentication is not used in the attached log.

Can't be the public key authentication disabled in client configuration or priorities of authentication methods modified that the `publickey` authentication is not used?

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because it lead me to the solution. I deleted the entry for this server in my local config and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

What does `/var/log/messages` show? How about when you run from the client `ssh -vvv <ip-address>`

How about using [these commands](http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/):
To create the keys.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

to copy the keys to server

```
ssh-copy-id user@onthmachineyouwanttoconnect
```

Comment: I won't get into the dsa/rsa debate :-) but, that should make no difference.
The copy method you posted is how I copied my local rsa to the remote.

I edited my question and included a link to a redacted instance of the ssh -vvv results.

Comment: No one should be using dsa keys these days.

Comment: Try setting GSSAPIAuthentication no in sshd_config. Anything in /var/log/messages?

Comment: @RobbieTheK I set GSSAPI to no - no effect other than it is now skipped in the handshake. /var/log/messages - for what should I look?

Comment: tail -f the log file in real time to see if any selinux messages appear. You restarted sshd after making the change, correct?